# How to select elements based on conditions in cypress/javascript

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a table below that displays different odds:

[image]

What happens is that the user will select an odds button to add their selection to a bet slip. However, what I need to do is select the correct button. What I mean by that is that it needs to select the first avilable odds button, not to select an odds button that is disabled or already selected.

So the my logic is this:

- Look in the odds table you see in the image and in the table row, check within to see if the button is not disabled and not selected.
- If the above is true, then take the name of the selection and store it as an alias and then click on that odds button.

Currently this is my code but I don't think it's 100% correct, it is selecting an odds button but not sure if it will do the check if the button is disabled or selected in the row. At the moment it is selecting the first odds button but that's because none of the buttons are currently selected or disabled (and it's a live site so no way to manipulate the site to fit the scenario).

Here is the HTML that matches the image above:

```
<div class="featuredOutright__content featuredOutright__content--primary">
   <ul class="featuredOutright__markets">
      <li id="betBundle__4192262052__wrapper" class="featuredOutright__selection">
         <div class="marketsList__image" id="betBundle__4192262052__sportIcon">
            <i class="icon-football"></i>
         </div>
         <div class="marketsList__detail">
            <i class="icon-shape icon-shape--rhombus icon-odds-boost"></i>
            <div class="marketsList__market__title" id="betBundle__4192262052__marketTitle">
               Club Brugge KV to score over 0.5 goals in each half
               <a class="marketsList__market__matchName textLink" href="#/soccer/event/20213522" id="betBundle__4192262052__eventLink">
               Club Brugge KV - KV Oostende
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="marketsList__was">
            <p class="marketsList__was-amount strikethrough--horizontal" id="betBundle__4192262052__previousPrice">
               5/6
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="marketsList__amount selectionBlock">
            <a id="event-selection-4192262052" eventid="event-selection-20213522" title="Club Brugge KV to score over 0.5 goals in each half" eventmodule="ODDS_BOOSTS_HOMEPAGE" class="oddsBoostedPrice   button__bet eventSelection--link" "="">
               <i class="icon-tick"></i>
               <em class="button__bet__odds">10/11</em>
               <div class="button__bet--action" data-textadded="Added" data-textremoved="Removed"></div>
            </a>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li id="betBundle__4192270554__wrapper" class="featuredOutright__selection">
         <div class="marketsList__image" id="betBundle__4192270554__sportIcon">
            <i class="icon-football"></i>
         </div>
         <div class="marketsList__detail">
            <i class="icon-shape icon-shape--rhombus icon-odds-boost"></i>
            <div class="marketsList__market__title" id="betBundle__4192270554__marketTitle">
               US Lecce to score over 0.5 goals in each half
               <a class="marketsList__market__matchName textLink" href="#/soccer/event/20213510" id="betBundle__4192270554__eventLink">
               Benevento - Lecce
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="marketsList__was">
            <p class="marketsList__was-amount strikethrough--horizontal" id="betBundle__4192270554__previousPrice">
               3/1
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="marketsList__amount selectionBlock">
            <a id="event-selection-4192270554" eventid="event-selection-20213510" title="US Lecce to score over 0.5 goals in each half" eventmodule="ODDS_BOOSTS_HOMEPAGE" class="oddsBoostedPrice   button__bet eventSelection--link" "="">
               <i class="icon-tick"></i>
               <em class="button__bet__odds">10/3</em>
               <div class="button__bet--action" data-textadded="Added" data-textremoved="Removed"></div>
            </a>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li id="betBundle__4196565633__wrapper" class="featuredOutright__selection">
         <div class="marketsList__image" id="betBundle__4196565633__sportIcon">
            <i class="icon-tennis"></i>
         </div>
         <div class="marketsList__detail">
            <i class="icon-shape icon-shape--rhombus icon-odds-boost"></i>
            <div class="marketsList__market__title" id="betBundle__4196565633__marketTitle">
               A Zverev and F Auger Aliassime to win the first set of the match
               <a class="marketsList__market__matchName textLink" href="#/tennis/outrights/20405610" id="betBundle__4196565633__eventLink">
               Odds Boost - Tennis
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="marketsList__was">
            <p class="marketsList__was-amount strikethrough--horizontal" id="betBundle__4196565633__previousPrice">
               7/1
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="marketsList__amount selectionBlock">
            <a id="event-selection-4196565633" eventid="event-selection-20405610" title="A Zverev and F Auger Aliassime to win the first set of the match" eventmodule="ODDS_BOOSTS_HOMEPAGE" class="oddsBoostedPrice   button__bet eventSelection--link" "="">
               <i class="icon-tick"></i>
               <em class="button__bet__odds">9/1</em>
               <div class="button__bet--action" data-textadded="Added" data-textremoved="Removed"></div>
            </a>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my step definition and elements class:

```
import { Given, When, Then } from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps";
import OddsSelectionElements from '../elements/oddsSelectionElements';

const oddsSelectionElements = new OddsSelectionElements();

When ("User selects an available bet bundle selection", () => {

  oddsSelectionElements.featuredSelectionRow()
  .within(() => {
    oddsSelectionElements.oddsButton().first().not(".disabled");
    oddsSelectionElements.oddsButton().first().not(".selected");
    oddsSelectionElements.marketListTitle().first().invoke("text").as("betBundleTitle");
    oddsSelectionElements.oddsButton().first().click();
  })
})
```

OddsSelectionElements:

```
class OddsSelectionElements {

    oddsButton() {
        return cy.get('.button__bet__odds')
    }

    featuredSelectionRow() {
        return cy.get('.featuredOutright__selection')
     }
 
     marketListTitle() {
         return cy.get('.marketsList__market__title')
     }
}

export default OddsSelectionElements
```

Example of button selected: it adds `selected` in class for the `<a>` tag

```
 <a id="event-selection-4192270554" eventid="event-selection-20213510" title="US Lecce to score over 0.5 goals in each half" eventmodule="ODDS_BOOSTS_HOMEPAGE" class="oddsBoostedPrice   button__bet eventSelection--link selected" "="">
```

disabled is same concept as above but instead of `selected` will add `disabled`

Comment: So these texts 10/11, 10/3 are the buttons you want to check whether they are disabled or enabled ? Also can you add the html for how a disabled button or already selected button looks like?

Comment: @AlapanDas Yes that's correct. I have added a html example of what happens when a button is selected. It just adds 'selected' class to the <a> of the button. For disabled, it's same concept but will be 'disabled'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `not(".disabled")` and `.not(".selected")` works above, you can write something like this:

```js
cy.get(".button__bet__odds").each(($ele, index) => {
  if ($ele.not(":disabled") && $ele.not(":selected")) {
    cy.get("marketsList__market__title").eq(index).invoke("text").as("someText")
    cy.wrap($ele).click()
    return false
  }
})

//Access someText
cy.get("@someText").then((someText) => {
  cy.log(someText) //Access someText here
})
```

Comment: Hi Alapan, I will give this a go but I do have one question, before I click the button, I need to store the value of the name of the selection. This is so later on I can check if the selection is added onto the bet slip. You can see in my example in the question I call on an element to get the text: .`marketsList__market__title`. Do you know how I should add this in the code? Hope that makes sense if you don't mind updating your answer to handle this?

Comment: Thank you Alapan, will give this a try and let you know. Just for my understanding as I am new to javascript, so if I look at your code, you're saying for for each odds button, if it's not disabled or selected, then get the name of the selection based on the matching index between the button and the selection name. and then click on the button. And I am assuming I just need to add a break to break out of the look if the if statement matches

Comment: Yes the index position of the not selected/disabled button is what we want then we can use the same index to extract the value. To break out from `each` add `return false`

Comment: Ah that return false is helpful as I was seeing compilation error when I tried break. Just running it..

Comment: Awesome, it worked Alapan. Thank you :) I was hoping if you don't mind, I do have a couple of general  questions I like to ask about cypress (especially debugging). Am I ok to ask this to you in a conversation through SO? It's just so I can test the test if that makes sense?

Comment: Hey. Glad you were able to figure it out. I am not sure how much help I would be but we can always give it a try. Also, it's always a good idea to create questions on whatever doubts you have.

Comment: Cool, will do that if I am still stuck. Thanks man